# Vim fugitive with neovim terminal emulator

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-fugitive

I recently switched from vim to neovim, installing the vim-fugitive plugin. Before, running `:Git rebase -i` in vim bought up the interactive rebase window in a vim window which I could edit as I needed to, `:x` out of the window and the rebase would be performed.

Now, in neovim, running the same rebase command brings up a terminal emulator buffer with the interactive rebase within. The emulator is non modifiable until I enter terminal mode pressing `I`. I can then edit the commits as I need to but how do I then close the emulator to carry out the rebase? Is there a way to prevent the terminal emulator coming up after running `:Git` commands? I've had a look through the vim-fugitive documentation but can't find anything about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Insert the following into your init.vim:

```
tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>
tnoremap <C-v><Esc> <Esc>
```

Now you can leave the terminal-mode with `<Esc>`.